# It's possible create a dataframe with parcial multiIndex columns?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

Something like this:

[image]

Note that the first and last field are single columns.

Comment: Elliot's answer is correct, but what are you trying to do ? are you triyng to create an output for excel?

Answer (score 0):

No, once you've got multiple levels in your columns, each column needs a level value for each.

If you're just looking for presentable output, those values can be an empty string. They can also be the same value at each level.

But if you select on the first two columns of the first level, you're going to have four columns at the second level, and pandas will need to know what to call all four.